# Using a flow builder and asFlow error that should call from suspend function

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I have the following interface to fetch recipes

```
interface FoodService {
    @GET(EndPoint.COMPLEX_SEARCH)
    suspend fun fetchComplexSearch(@Query("apiKey") apiKey: String): ResultModel
}
```

This works find using a flow builder

```
override fun complexSearch(apiKey: String): Flow<List<ComplexSearchEntity>> {
    return flow {
        val resultModel = foodService.fetchComplexSearch(apiKey)

        val listOfComplexSearchEntity = resultModel.results.map { complexSearchModel ->
            mapperDataToDomain.map(complexSearchModel)
        }

        emit(listOfComplexSearchEntity)
    }
}
```

However, I get an error when I use the extension `asFlow`

```
override fun complexSearch(apiKey: String): Flow<List<ComplexSearchEntity>> {
    return foodService.fetchComplexSearch(apiKey).results.map {
        mapperDataToDomain.map(it)
    }.asFlow()
}
```

Error 1

```
Required:
Flow<List<ComplexSearchEntity>>
Found:
Flow<ComplexSearchEntity>
```

Error 2

```
Suspend function 'fetchComplexSearch' should be called only from a coroutine or another suspend function
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't do the same thing at all, hence the error.

In the first case, `complexSearch` immediately returns a cold flow without doing any work. No code from the lambda is executed, so no need to suspend anything. The *collector* of this cold flow will provide a coroutine environment for the collection and the suspension. Each time the collector asks for a new element, the content of your `flow { ... }` lambda will proceed until the next `emit()`.

In the second case, you're performing all the work immediately to build a list, and only then convert that list into a flow before returning it. So all your asynchronism happens immediately and needs to be executing in a coroutine. The flow is just a wrapper around the list in this case.

Also, I'm not sure the code is doing what you want, because you're returning a flow of a single element (at least in the first case). This is usually better served by a suspend function rather than a `Flow`, which also better informs the users that this is a one-shot call. An API returning a `Flow` of a single element is misleading because the users of this API would likely expect to susbcribe to this flow and get updates.

Comment: Also, adding to why the resulting type doesn't match. Original code emitted a single element which was a list. On the other hand `list.asFlow()` "unpacks" items of a list and makes them items of a flow, so list is removed from the type signature. Equivalent of the original code would be: `flowOf(list)`.